# sqlcmd does not create parameters on a backup file name when executed through Powershell or Command line

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd

I want to create an automated backup of some databases on a SQL Server 2017 Express instance and so I used this: [How to schedule and automate backups of SQL Server databases in SQL Server Express](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2019698/how-to-schedule-and-automate-backups-of-sql-server-databases-in-sql-se).

I thought I'd just run the resulting `sp_BackupDatabases` via a PowerShell script through Task Scheduler as there was other automation to do with the backups.

I created a PowerShell script to execute `sp_BackupDatabases` as follows:

```
sqlcmd -S .\MYSQLEXPRESS2017INSTANCE -E -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation='C:\MAYBACKUPLOCATION\', @databaseName='MYDB', @backupType='F'"
```

This does indeed create a backup file in the designated location, but *does not* append the date and time or the `.BAK` extension as the stored procedure defines.  I just get a file without an extension called 'MYDB_FULL'. The file is fine other than this i.e. I could just rename it 'MYDB_FULL_MYDATE.BAK'.  No errors are reported.

If I execute this through SQL Server Management Studio (SMS) using the debugger, I can see all is fine and the full file name is created along with a `.BAK` extension.

I experimented and created a SQL script that does exactly as the stored procedure does. Again, executed through SSMS and all is fine, but not when called through `sqlcmd` (either in PowerShell or from the command prompt).

If I do rename the file and inspect it through SSMS, it has named it correctly (using `@BackupName` variable) and so it I know is generating the time and date variables and appending them as per the script.

If it makes any difference the SQL Server 2017 Express instance is running alongside a SQL Server 2014 Express instance on Windows Server 2012R2 (which is not a DC).

It's a trivial thing to rename the file, but what am I missing?!

Comment: What is the sql for `sp_BackupDatabases`? If you're saying it does the renaming there, that's the SQL we need to see.

Comment: Thanks Larnu - The Microsoft link had the full code, so to save space I left it out, which in hindsight was wrong...!

Answer (score 1):

After hours of scratching my head I have just found the answer - its a classic programming error and a case of me missing the absolute obvious because it only missed the time and .BAK appends to the file name.  It could have been anything.

I reused Microsoft's code for creating the SP sp_BackupDatabases.  It was simple case of space in the variable names.  I have reposted a gist of my correction to the code in case others see this issue.  The two variables are

```
@backupLocation nvarchar(200)
...
DECLARE @BackupFile varchar(100)
```

There is a point in the script where the file name is created:

```
SET @BackupFile = @backupLocation+REPLACE(REPLACE(@DBNAME, '[',''),']','')+ '_FULL_'+ @dateTime+ '.BAK'
```

So the issue was that in my case, the backup location is temporarily in a place with a long path name.  When @backupFile, of size var(100) was set to a location that could take up to 200 chars, it was not going top end well and just truncated without error...

For those interested the full code is here on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/chumkui/cf00e10aa7fe8341ad89898876e13c45) to save space.